# Find the positive integer solutions of the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all positive integer solutions of the following equation ,

$(x+2y)^2$ + $2x$ + $5y$ + $9$ = $(y+z)^2$

I tried the problem on my own and got ,

$(x+2y)^2  -  (y+z)^2  = -( 2x +  5y +9)$

$(x+3y+z)(x+y-z)  =  -(2x+5y+9)$

Now since $x,y,z$ are positive integers  the right hand side of the above equation must be negative and $(x+3y+z)$ must be positive

So, $(x+y-z)<0$

or, $x+y<z$

since they are integers we can conclude that,

$x+y+1\le z$.

Then I did some experiment by putting in $x=1,y=1$ and $z=3,4$ and got $x=1,y=1,z=4$ for the answer. But how do I prove that this is the only solution (if it is).

Comment: Hint: For all but finitely many values, $|(2x+5y+9)/(x+3y+z)| \leq 2$.

Comment: What does for all but finitely many values mean ? English is not my native language

Comment: It means "except for a finite number of cases". EG Try solving the inequality in positive integer.

Comment: After seeing your hint I got till $x+y-z \le 1$ when I input that into the equation  I get your equation , but what do I do now ?

Comment: (1, 1, 3) is not a solution.

Comment: yeah (1,1,3) is not but (1,1,4) is

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you meant. It wasn't clear that you were testing those 2 cases (or why only those 2 cases).

Answer (score 2):

Fill in the gaps. If you are stuck, show your work.

- Show that $0 < \frac{ 2x+5y+9}{x+3y+z} < 2 $ iff $9 < y + 2z$.
- Hence if $ 9 < y + 2z$, then $x+y - z = -1$ and $x+3y+z = 2x+5y + 9$.

  - What is the solution here?
- Show that $\frac{ 2x+5y+9}{x+3y+z} = 2 $ iff $9 = y + 2z$.
- Hence if $ 9 = y + 2z$, then $ x+ y - z = -2$ and $ 2(x+3y+z) =  2x+5y+9$.

  - What is the solution here?
- Otherwise, if $ 9 > y + 2z$, run through each of the cases and see if there is a corresponding $x$.

  - What is the solution here?
  - Is there a better approach than just trial and error? Possibly, but we only have 8 cases to check, so I didn't bother thinking further.
- Hence, what are all of the solutions? Are there more than what you listed?

Comment: I will try this and get back to you